# In the context of file-handling in C++ console application; max characters displayability without horizontal scrolling?

Tags: c++

My professor today was teaching us File handling in C++. He made a very simple program which would read two lines from a text file and display those on the screen using fin.getline() function. He chose the size of the array which was storing the read line to be of 80 characters. He then proceeded to explain that it MUST be taken as 80 because one line "on the screen" consists of 80 characters.

I couldn't really understand what he was saying. The amount of characters appearing on the screen, isn't that screen/font/resolution dependent?

Even in compilers as old as Borland and Turbo C++, wasn't there a way to change how many characters would display on the screen when say (assuming wrapping is on) ?

I couldn't get his concept of hard and fast "80 characters". Please explain?

Comment: Maybe you should ask him for an explanation, since in our world the 80 characters have nothing to do with reading lines from a file.

Comment: Also, code to get the console window details (e.g. line length) would be very compiler / OS specific. Hopefully you have code handle if a line in the file is "bigger than one line on the screen".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can conclude that your professor hasn't worked on a computer
since the late 1980's/early 1990's, at least.  A very long time ago
(when I was learning C), lines of the screen were 80 characters (because
punch cards were 80 characters); it was a hardware constraint, and there
was nothing you could do about it.  (There wasn't any `'{'`, `'}'`, or
`'|'` on the keyboard, either.  Which made editing C code a bit of a
pain as well.)

Today, of course, lines can be any length; even then, lines in a file
could be any length, and editors used either horizonal scrolling or line
wrap to display them.  And C++ has a standard type, `std::string`, which
handles this very well: you don't use `fin.getline(buffer)`, you use
`std::getline(fin, buffer)`, where `buffer` is declared as an 
`std::string`, and you don't worry about the length.  (Almost.  If you
run into a line that's more than a couple of billion characters long,
you're likely to run into problems.)

My suggestion is to find a different professor, because either you've
misunderstood or misinterpreted something he said, or he doesn't seem to
know what he's talking about.

Comment: It's not unusual for computer science professors to have no clue what they're on about, when it comes to trying to state facts about programming.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal So I've heard, but never having seen a windowing system (Windows, Mac, X)?

Comment: @JamesKanze

Ohh he definitely works on newer machines :P. I guess, some people just are (unfortunately) not even slightly intuitive and perceptive.

Answer (score 3):

> He chose the size of the array which was storing the read line to be
>   of 80 characters. He then proceeded to explain that it MUST be taken
>   as 80 because one line "on the screen" consists of 80 characters.
>
> I couldn't really understand what he was saying. The amount of
>   characters appearing on the screen, isn't that screen/font/resolution
>   dependent?

Yes, exactly.

> I couldn't get his concept of hard and fast "80 characters". Please explain?

It's complete nonsense. C++ doesn't specify any such thing, and any terminal is capable of configuration.

Comment: And what does the screen have to do with the length of lines in a file?  Even when 80 characters was the hardware determined width of a screen, editors could wrap lines, and files could have lines of more or less any length.  (132 characters was common, because that was the width of a line on the line printers of the time.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes, that's what I just said.

Answer (score 2):

I would always favor the  version of getline which resides in string as you will not need to pre-allocate space. It is very short sighted to insist on 80 char limits as you will not mostly be manipulating text for the purpose of displaying it on text consoles.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string strLine;
   ifstream fin("file.txt");
   //Usual tests for successful open go here

   getline(fin, strLine); //no need to pre-allocate

   cout << strLine << endl;

   fin.close();

   return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about 80 characters anymore. Hardcoding a fixed-size buffer is dangerous and a Bad Idea. Even if the terminal will only display 80 characters, you should leave it to the terminal to worry about that.

The reason that you can't get the concept is because, well, it doesn't really exist anymore.

Comment: Well, if he's reading from a punched card reader, it may still be relevant:-).  But I can remember dealing with lines longer than 80 characters as early as the mid 1970's, and I haven't seen a device with this restriction anywhere since around 1990.